# Как вывести коды символов ASCII в С++?

Tags: c++, кодировка

Моя программа:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(0, "");
unsigned char a='Б', b='А', c='Й', d='Т';
cout << int (a) << " " << int (b) << " " << int (c) << " " << int (d) << 
endl;
cout << "Vvedite  БАЙТ ";
cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
cout << int (a) << " " << int (b) << " " << int (c) << " " << int (d) << 
endl;
cin.get(); cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Итоги работы программы такие:

193 192 201 210
Vvedite БАЙТ БАЙТ
129 128 137 146

Сначала отображаются коды символов из кодовой таблицы 1251 – MS Windows, а затем из кодовой таблицы 866 – MS-DOS. Как сделать так чтобы сразу же, в первой строке отображались коды из таблицы 866 – MS-DOS, без предварительного ввода символов с клавиатуры?

Comment: Visual Studio??

Comment: Dew-C++........

Comment: Поищите в настройках параметры сохранения файлов исходного кода и смените кодировку на DOS 866. Возможно, для ваших целей этого будет достаточно.

Comment: Просто пишите свою программу в 866 кодировке. Или выполняйте преобразование - это не так уж и сложно.

Comment: А ещё можно на gcc возложить перекодировку `-finput-charset=<своя кодировка> -fexec-charset=866`. Первый параметр, возможно, не обязателен.